# Why cant i install Angular Bootstrap?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, bootstrap-4, node-modules

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.3
Node: 16.15.1
Package Manager: npm 8.12.1 
OS: darwin x64
```

I am installing angular bootstrap (trying to) getting the following error from NPM

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: tractapp@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@14.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.2" from @angular/animations@14.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"14.2.2" from @angular/platform-browser@14.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.4.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!         @angular/fire@"^7.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!       6 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!     2 more (@swimlane/ngx-charts, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.2.2" from @angular/material@14.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=12.0.0" from @swimlane/ngx-charts@20.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-charts
npm ERR!       @swimlane/ngx-charts@"^20.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (ng2-charts, the root project)
npm ERR!   16 more (@angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/fire, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@14.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.6" from @angular/forms@14.2.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^14.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^14.1.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

NPM errors and how these are stated is not my strong suit of understanding, would love if someone could help me out and point me in the right direction here.

Thanks!

Heres my package.json file aswell, im assuming its something in there by the way the error is formed/stated.

```
{
  "name": "tractapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.11.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.37.0",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^12.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-stripe": "^14.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "stripe": "^10.11.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick look at the github releases page for `ng-bootstrap` shows that they only support up to Angular `14.1` but your version is `14.2.2`. My bet is, this is some version incompatibility

Comment: seems like your right, i have managed to just import standard bootstrap, however i know it may get a little complicated as i continue with bootstrap, 
thanks for the help! and saving my time for trying to fix it

Comment: @sinanspd feel free to answer as an answer so i can mark it as right!

Comment: No problem. NPM sucks and the angular error message isnt very helpful. Putting this here since its not an answer but I find Angular Material much more convenient. There is overlap with some of what bootstrap accomplishes and is usually up to date as both are maintained by Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the comment to an answer per OP's request and so that the question can be marked resolved.

Looking at the [Github releases page](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases) (accessed on 10/12/22 for v 13.0.0) the maximum support for the library currently is Angular 14.1, where as you are using 14.2.2. This seems to be a version compatibility issue (essentially the library is trying to pull an older version of Angular and you are getting a conflict)

You either have to downgrade you Angular version or use something else

Answer (score 1):

npm update was perfect to me :D

Answer (score 0):

Run npm update before installing ng bootstrap in your vs code terminal, that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I added `@angular/service-worker` to my ionic project.
The angular version required by `@angular/service-worker` is different from the version installed at the beginning, and they conflict.
`package-lock.json` retains the version of angular that was originally installed
So, you can try to delete `package-lock.json` and rerun `npm install`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).